# Is there a way to define dissonance such that it can be quantifiable?

Tags: theory, consonance-and-dissonance

We can perceive dissonance between notes, but are is there a mathematical way to  measure the relationship between two notes as more or less dissonant?

Context: I'm doing an experiment with sets of two singers to see if they are more or less harmonious based on the harmonic overtones recorded from the notes they sing.